# Expand linux memory to disk

Tags: linux, memory, busybox

I know you can create RAM Disks but is there a way to turn disk space from say a USB drive to RAM?

I have a small router based device with SSH and I would like to install a side app on it. The downside right now looks to be the lack of memory. It's only 256MB with 100 free right now. I would like to throw FOP2 on this myPBX device but concerned the lack of ram might be an issue for a webpage service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mkswap` to create a swap file or disk and then use `swapon` on it.

If you don't want to format your whole device to swap, you can simply create a file of desired size, e.g. with `dd if=/dev/zero of=yourswap bs=1 count=N`, where N is number of bytes.